# AngularJS proper way of refreshing data in Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a testing "hello" view showing "Hello {{username}}!" or "Hello anonymous!".
This view has its own controller and is accesible via url (configure by ui.router).

Then I have a UserModel with methods `setUsername(newUsername)` and `getUsername()`.

There is also logging view with a controller that uses `setUsername()` method on logging in success and then navigates to "hello" view.

The code looks like this:

HelloController:

```
anguler.module('hello', ...
.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('hello', {
            url: '/hello',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    controller: 'HelloController as helloController',
                    templateUrl: 'app/hello/hello-tmpl.html'
                }
            },
        });
})
.controller('HelloController', function (UserModel) {
    var helloController = this;
    helloController.username = UserModel.getUsername();
})
```

There is also a "log out" button in the top bar. So in order to show the changes in "hello" view I added a list of function that `UserModel` would call when user state changes:

```
.service('UserModel', function() {
    var model = this;

    var username = '';
    var onChangesFunctions = [];

    function onChange() {
        onChangesFunctions.forEach(function(f) {
            f();
        });
    }

    model.onChange = function(f) {
        onChangesFunctions.push(f);
    };

    model.setUsername = function(newUsername) {
        username = newUsername;
        onChange();
    };

    model.clearUserData = function() {
        username = '';
        onChange();
    };
```

and added a code in `HelloController` to add a listener to the `UserModel.onChangesFunctions`.

The problem with that approach is that `HelloController` is initialized many times (everytime that user navigates to it) and every time it is registering new function as the listener.

Is there any better way to refresh user data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your approach is memory leaks. As you said when your controller is destroyed and the new one is created your function will still persist in the service and the controller which should have been killed is still most likely in the memory because of the function.

I don't clearly understand what your goal is; however what you can do is destroying the functions when the controller is destroyed:

```
.controller('HelloController', function (UserModel, $scope) {
    var helloController = this;
    helloController.username = UserModel.getUsername();

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      // either destroy all functions you add to the service queue
      // or
      // simply call the controller specific logic here, this will be called when your controller is destroyed
    });
});
```

Another approach is listening on '$stateChangeStart' / '$stateChangeSuccess' event.

Regardless of the way you choose I would highly recommend to avoid binding services to the controller instance specific logic. This is a way to hell